# Building WordPress Themes With Bootstrap with Adi Purdila → TutsPlus

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I started to learn from a wordpress video tutorials on Tutsplus. [Click Here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/building-wordpress-themes-with-bootstrap).
Adi Purdila has created a function on that Tutorial →

```
/* ------------------------------------------------ */
/* 4. NUMBERED PAGINATION */
/* ------------------------------------------------ */
if ( ! function_exists( 'tuts_numbered_pagination' ) ) {
    function tuts_numbered_pagination() {
        $args = array(
            'prev_next' => false,
            'type' => 'array'
        );

        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
        $pagination = paginate_links( $args );

        if ( is_array( $pagination ) ) {
            echo '<ul class="nav nav-pills">';
            foreach ( $pagination as $page ) {
                if ( strpos( $page, 'current' ) ) {
                    echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">' . $page . '</a></li>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
                }
            }

            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand this function. Although I can understand markups such as why its been echoed etc, but there are many things that I do not understand, for example →

'prev_next' => false,
prev_next' → **is it something predefined in wordpress?**

$page → This no where defined; How come Adi Purdila is using it? Is it some kind of global variable.

P.S. to many experts my question will look stupid, but please bear with me as I am a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, [`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) is being called and is expected to return an array of links.

```
$args = array(
    'prev_next' => false,
    'type' => 'array'
);
```

[`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) - Retrieve paginated link for archive post pages. Technically, the function can be used to create paginated link list for any area ( e.g.: « Prev 1 … 3 4 5 6 7 … 9 Next » )

- **prev_next** (boolean) (optional) Whether to include the previous and next links in the list or not.
- **type** (string) (optional) Controls format of the returned value. Possible values are:

  - 'plain' - A string with the links separated by a newline character.
  - 'array' - An array of the paginated link list to offer full control of display.
  - 'list' - Unordered HTML list.

The next bits are looping through each page. The `as` lets you define any variable name you want to represent the value, the tutorial chose `$page`.

```
foreach ( $pagination as $page )
```

If it contains the term `current` then extra attributes are added to mark it for styling.

```
strpos( $page, 'current' )
```

Example output of the function might look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
    [1] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/2/'>2</a>
    [2] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/3/'>3</a>
    [3] => <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
    [4] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/7/'>7</a>
)
```

With `prev_next` set to `true` you would see something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://example.com/">« Previous</a>
    [1] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/'>1</a>
    [2] => <span class='page-numbers current'>2</span>
    [3] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/3/'>3</a>
    [4] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/4/'>4</a>
    [5] => <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
    [6] => <a class='page-numbers' href='http://example.com/page/7/'>7</a>
    [7] => <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://example.com/page/3/">Next »</a>
)
```

If you want to experiment and check the output try:

```
$args = array (
        'prev_next' => true,
        'type'      => 'array',
);
echo "<pre>";
ob_start();
print_r( paginate_links( $args ) );
esc_html_e( ob_get_clean() );
```

Comment: Sir, As you said → prev_next (boolean) (optional) Whether to include the previous and next links in the list or not.
_______
What does this means sir. Is prev_next pre defined in wordpress. If this is true then I believe we can't use previous_next. Right Sir?

Comment: @WordpressNovice - I've updated the answer to include output for true/false of prev_next. As for what does prev_next mean... this is creating pagination, so the previous page, and the next page. Usually this shows up when `/page/2/` is added in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

paginate_links is the function that will create a pagination, look into it, you will find some predefined arguments.
Here is codex documentation link for the paginate_links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Here the author of that tutorial is trying to modify it according to requirement of theme. Prev_next is the predefined argument of paginate_links function that will decide wether to show next and prev button in pagination or not.

Just read the documentation and you will understand how it works.

Comment: @WordpressNovice let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I need lots of help does this website also provide chatting option?